# Delete files in a folder in perl

Tags: perl

Im trying to delete all the files in the directory called spool but it doesent  work... Im trying to use Unlink

```
    unlink glob "$dir/*home/roz/newfolder/spool*";
```

is the code im trying to use but it doesent work

Comment: in what way does it not work?

Comment: Doesen't empty the folder....

Comment: The files are called spool or the directories are called spool. If it's the latter, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you have permission to delete those files?  What is the error message?  `unlink $file or die "Unable to unlink '$file' : $!;`

Comment: Its the directories that are called spool and i want to delete everything inside the directory...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Simply saying "it doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem. Since your post is lacking detail, I can only give you two suggestions: 1. Check the return value of `glob()`. Is it globbing the files you want? 2. Loop over the files returned by `glob()` and try to delete them one at a time. `unlink($file) or die $!` will give you an error message if something goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `spool*` did not return the files in 'spool' folder, but rather - all files in folder 'newfolder' with name starting with 'spool'.

To get all the files in a folder named 'spool' use:

```
glob("$dir/*home/roz/newfolder/spool/*");
```

To get all hidden files in the 'spool' folder use:

```
glob("$dir/*home/roz/newfolder/spool/.*");
```

And finally, are you sure that '*home' is that what you really want?
If it is a typo, and you've meant 'home' it will be more clear and error-prone(you don't have to care about hidden files or files with spaces in the name) to use

`my $path = "$dir/home/roz/newfolder/spool";
opendir(my $sdir, $path) or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
unlink  map { "$path/$_" if -f "$path/$_" } readdir $sdir;`

Comment: `readdir` returns local names (including `.` and `..`). You shouldn't unlink them from the current working directory.

Comment: @melpomene: check perldoc -f unlink:    
  
Note: "unlink" will not attempt to delete directories unless you are superuser and the -U flag is supplied to Perl. Even if these conditions are met, be warned that unlinking a directory can inflict damage on your filesystem. Finally, using "unlink" on directories is not supported on many operating systems. Use "rmdir" instead.     
Though, I agree is a good practice to be over-careful and to do: `next if /..?/;`

Comment: I meant: `/^..?$/`, of course.   
But in the case given `unlink grep {-f } readdir $sdir` is more elegant.

Comment: Again, `readdir` returns local names. You can't pass them to `-f` or `unlink` if you're not in the directory you're reading from.

Comment: @melpomene: yes, this time you're absolutely right (I was tested in perl comand line). I'll edit my answer again while you read the unlink docs :)

Comment: What do you mean, "this time"? I merely repeated my comment.

Comment: @melpomene: your first comment was misleading in that the unlink will try to delete the  '.'  and  '..' folders. And I did not get the part with "local".